# issues with "/" in a url using window.open in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

The url I want to share is a simple http://www.mysite.com/123.php
This code doesn't work.  I've tried encodeURIComponent and encodeURI with no luck.

```
<script>
function fbs_click(id) {

u='http://www.mysite.com/';
t = id + '.php';

window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=Check it out&p[url]='+u+t,'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');

}
</script>
```

The open window at facebook shows "check it out" then www.mysite.com.
It doesn't show any "/" or the stuff after .com

If I get rid of the "/" after .com and have

```
u='http://www.mysite.com';
t = id + '.php';
```

The open window shows "check it out" and www.mysite.com123.php so the issue must have to do with the forward slash.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
function fbs_click(id) {

u='http://www.mysite.com/';
t = id + '.php';

window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=Check it out&p[url]='+u+'\'+t,'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');

}
</script>
```

did you tried appending '\' seperately???

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code its working fine

```
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=Check it out&p[url]='+u+'/'+t,'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
```